# How can I display data passed to the view from the express router in react?

Tags: express, reactjs, pug

Routing code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {username: req.session['passport']['user']['username']});
}
```

In my jade template, I can very easily display the data like this:

```
h2= username
```

I'd like to display this username object in my react component, something like this:

```
var Account = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <h2>
        {username}
      </h2>
    )
  }
});
```

How do I pass this information to my react component?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this data in a couple of ways.

Either embed the data in your DOM or a `script` tag and after you've loaded your scripts and it's time to render you React component fetch the data from the DOM.

```
<div class="data" style="display: none;" data-data="YOUR DATA GOES HERE STRINGIFIED" />

React.render(<YourComponent data={document.querySelector('.data').dataset.data} />, document.querySelector('.yourContainer'));
```

or open an endpoint to your data

```
router.get('/myData', function(req, res) {
  res.render({username: req.session['passport']['user']['username']});
}
```

Then in your component, using the lifecycle method `componentDidMount` fetch it.

```
componentDidMount: function () {
   someAjaxLib.get('/myData').success(function (data) {
      this.setState({data: data});
   }.bind(this));
}
```